# Build an app which animates a circle completing from 0 to 360 in android

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, android-canvas, android-bitmap

I want to build an app which animates a circle completing from 0 to 360 in android. I am new in android and working on animation

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        Path path = new Path();
        float center_x, center_y;

        center_x = width/2;
        center_y = height/2;
        final RectF oval = new RectF();
        oval.set(center_x - radius,center_y - radius,center_x + radius,center_y + radius);
        path.addArc(oval, 0, 360);// like this line produce a complete circle but i want animation which start from 0 and end at 360

        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```

I try to use while loop with invalidate(); but it did not work. So please help me.

Comment: you need a timer, other than while loop. because system need time to process your `invalidate()` and do the draw in real.

Comment: Jian YD, I can figure it out how to use timer to process time. Do you have some code or  example.